# InputStream read "reasonable" length of text, avoid blocking

Tags: java, inputstream, blocking

I'm trying to read character by character from user input, like so:

```
while ((i = System.in.read()) != -1) {
  // do stuff with input...
  char c = (char)i;

}
```

As expected, this blocks until end of stream is reached. From the documentation [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) allows for the `available()` to give an estimate of remaining bytes in data source.

Using this approach, i.e. checking `System.in.available() > 0`, instead gives rise to an exit from the while loop whenever a newline is encountered.

I need to read user input character by character for a "reasonable" length of text. I can assume that the length of any such text from user input is bounded by some `N`.

How is this best accomplished, if possible with a solution close to what I originally intended? The questions I have come across thus far do not seem to adress this, but I might be mistaken. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `InputStream.available()` is generally not a useful method and should be avoided.  you stated that you want to read up to N characters.  so why not just break out of your loop when you reach N characters and discard the rest of the input?

Comment: Also, you might want to check out [Console](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) which has some useful methods for reading input from the console.